# Applet and jackson external jars: Can not access public class

Tags: java, security, reflection, applet, jackson

i have an applet, in eclipse everything works right, but, when i export the jar, and embed to my website(which i have to embed every jackson jar too), im getting this error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not access public ticket.Ticket() (from class ticket.Ticket; failed to set access: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:272)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:247)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:146)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:322)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:2990)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2884)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)
at ticket.Main.init(Main.java:56)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.init(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not access public ticket.Ticket() (from class ticket.Ticket; failed to set access: access denied ("java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission" "suppressAccessChecks")
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.checkAndFixAccess(ClassUtil.java:510)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCollector._fixAccess(CreatorCollector.java:203)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCollector.setDefaultConstructor(CreatorCollector.java:106)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.CreatorCollector.setDefaultCreator(CreatorCollector.java:123)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._addDeserializerConstructors(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:369)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory._constructDefaultValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:315)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BasicDeserializerFactory.findValueInstantiator(BasicDeserializerFactory.java:259)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:263)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:168)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:401)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:354)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:267)
... 10 more
```

What can i do in this case?

Comment: Can you show to us your Ticket class? I think, you did not implement default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An applet that attempts reflection would need to be [digitally signed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html) by the developer, and trusted by the user when prompted.

Comment: Well you should be able to do reflection for items that you would normally be able to access without reflection (roughly). This exception is from Jackson, and I've no idea what it attempting to do.

Comment: Thank you!, this worked, but now i have another problem, im using RXTX library and i get the NoClassDefError

Comment: `NoClassDefError` is a separate matter that should be asked about on ..a separate question.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to signing, you should be able to avoid this problem by disabling `MapperFeature.CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS`, (see [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#CAN_OVERRIDE_ACCESS_MODIFIERS)). This prevents specific call that is failing for you; for non-applet use case this is important for access and performance reasons; but it requires that security manager allows it.